# graphics noisey, trails, slow refresh?

Tags: graphics, debugging

Please help me figure this out.
Noisy graphics, like it takes time to refresh, when there is any movement on the screen.  It leaves trails of static-like noise during video play (see image), if I pause video the screen cleans itself up and everything looks fine.  Same problem occurs if I scroll a webpage (or any file window or menu), the text becomes noisy and unreadable, but if I stop and give it a second it will refresh itself and look fine.
I can also hear a very low-level digital static sound in conjunction with the noise on my screen.  Any audio or music streaming sounds fine.

I'm new to Linux so please be detailed and patient with me.
Latest Ubuntu Studio running on AMD Ryzen 5 2400G using Radeon Vega graphics and an MSI B450-a pro board.  Thanks.

[Noisy video image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qR9YH.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Solution can be found here:  https://sick.codes/screen-blurry-after-updating-arch-linux-amd-pixelated-artifacts-and-graphics-issue/

The new AMD Ryzen with Radeon graphics laptops, particularly the Ideapad & Thinkpads, have a problem with the Xfce window manager compositor.
 Go to Window Manager Tweaks and disable Window Compositing.